# Найти и исправить источник проблемы в итерации

Tags: python, django

Проблема которая встряла мне поперёк горла возможно находится на поверхности, но т.к я новичок в данной области - найти и решить своими силами не получается.

В чём заключается проблема:

При попытке добавить товар в корзину, выскакивает ошибка "**list indices must be integers or slices, not str**". Этапы её формирования можно посмотреть в трекбэке ниже...

> P.S. Серьёзно не пинайте, я в некоторых моментах даже не совсем
>   понимаю что и как работает. Но в общем то я всё и затеял чтобы
>   разобраться.
>
> **Если нужно - добавлю любой кусок кода который я упустил и может дать ответ.**

*Код который по моему должен дать понимание источника проблемы*

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    url(r'^remove/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
    url(r'^$', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
]
```

```
class Cart(object):

    # Добавление товара в корзину пользователя или обновление количества товара
    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = int(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': int(product.price),
                                     }
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity

        self.save()
```

```
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 21)]

class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

```
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.changed_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

---

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "D:\Projects\python\sportinia_e-landing\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "D:\Projects\python\sportinia_e-landing\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "D:\Projects\python\sportinia_e-landing\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\Projects\python\sportinia_e-landing\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\http.py"
>   in inner
>     40.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\Projects\python\sportinia_e-landing\sportinia_store\cart\views.py"
>   in cart_add
>     15.         cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /cart/add/3/ Exception Value: list
>   indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы обращаетесь с переменной `cd` как с словарём, то есть пытаетесь получить что-то по ключу (`cd['quantity']`), хотя `cd` - это список.

Атрибут формы [`changed_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data) возвращает список полей, чьи значения из переданных данных (обычно, `request.POST`) отличаются от значений из [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial). Возвращает пустой список, если данные не поменялись.

*Пример объекта:*

```py
['subject', 'message']
```

Думаю, Вы хотели использовать `cleaned_data` вместо этого.

Если форма прошла проверку, то [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) будет содержать ключ и значение для всех полей формы.

*Пример объекта:*

```py
{'cc_myself': True, 'message': 'Hi there', 'sender': 'foo@example.com', 'subject': 'hello'}
```